# Matlab Plot with Customize color

Tags: matlab

does anyone know what's the command or way to plot with different colors besides the preset color, i.e., b,g,r,c,m,y,k? I would prefer to use my own customize colors instead of these....

Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `Color` property with a `ColorSpec` triple:

```
plot(x, y, 'Color', [0.5, 1.0, 0.0], 'LineStyle', '--')
```

The vector here contains RGB values between `0.0` and `1.0`. The [Lineseries](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/lineseriesproperties.html) and [ColorSpec](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/colorspec.html) documentation entries have more information about this.

Comment: Thanks You! Where can I look for the color map as to decide what number between 0 - 1 to be input in the code? I have search for Lineseries, ColorSpec and Colormap but can't see what I want. The usual way of choosing from the pixel map is in the form of more than 1.

Comment: @kit: If you have a colormap (e.g. `hot`), IIRC you should get color `k` from the colormap using `cmap = colormap('hot'); cmap(k,:)`. If yo have color values ranging from 0 to 255, just divide by 255 to get the correct range.

Answer (score 0):

[From the matlab docs:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html)

> ColorOrder: m-by-3 matrix of RGB values
>
> Colors to use for multiline plots. Defines the colors used by the plot
>   and plot3 functions to color each line plotted. If you do not specify
>   a line color with plot and plot3, these functions cycle through the
>   ColorOrder property to obtain the color for each line plotted. To
>   obtain the current ColorOrder, which might be set during startup, get
>   the property value:
>
> get(gca,'ColorOrder') Note that if the axes NextPlot property is
>   replace (the default), high-level functions like plot reset the
>   ColorOrder property before determining the colors to use. If you want
>   MATLAB to use a ColorOrder that is different from the default, set
>   NextPlot to replacechildren. You can also specify your own default
>   ColorOrder.

All together, this means you want the commands:

```
figure();
axis();
set(gca, 'colororder', <color matrix>, 'nextplot', 'replacechildren');
plot(x,y);
```

Comment: I got what you meant on setting the color order. I have tried the following commands.                                             figure
set(gca, 'colororder', [1, 0.5, 0.753], 'nextplot', 'replacechildren');
plot(x,y)
figure
plot(x,z)
I don't know why am I getting default color again for the second figure, seems like I am not using nextplot and replacechildren correctly

Comment: Do you create and axis object with `axis()` before calling `set`?

Comment: Yes, I am adding now, but still getting the default color for the second plot. Here's my code: figure();
axis();
set(gca, 'colororder', [1, 0.5, 0.753], 'nextplot', 'replacechildren'); 
plot(x, y)
figure
plot(x, z) What does the axis() does? Why do we need ()?                                                                  By the way, I am making a mess when pasting matlab coding here. May I know what command I need to add before pasting my code and fit in the grey box like you did? I am new user for this kind of forum. Thanks!

Comment: You need the `axis` call so that an axis object exists upon which you can call `set`. You do not need the '()', as it is implied in matlab. To get it to work for your second plot, you'd have to call `axis` and `set` again. To have your code formatted as code, enclose it in backquotes (\`).

Comment: Thanks Isaac, I have tried the code you have suggested and it works. So each time I will need to use `set` command if I want to specify my own color code? Is this because my settings will be overwritten by the plot command each time I call it? Further on, I have tried the following code without the `axis` command as follows: 
`figure();
set(gca, 'colororder', [1, 0.5, 0.753], 'nextplot', 'replacechildren'); 
plot(x, y)
figure();
set(gca, 'colororder', [1, 0.5, 0.753], 'nextplot', 'replacechildren'); 
plot(x, z)` and it is still working.

Comment: Seems like using this `set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1, 0.5, 0.753;0.5, 0.5, 1;1, 1, 0.753])` will be able to set the color permanently in the following plots without using the `set` command each time before plotting.

Comment: Do you know where exactly is the color settings in the Figure itself? Is it in View -> Property Editor -> More Properties -> Color? I am not seeing the settings for 'colororder' or 'DefaultAxesColorOrder'? Where are they hiding?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the limited set of preset colours MATLAB made available. So, I created this page on my website, where you can choose from a large palette of non-standard colours, and the colour code is pasted directly to your clipboard:

http://www.shirt-ediss.me/matlab-octave-more-colours/